# Categorised Multiple File uploads within a page in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a situation where I have to upload multiple files within categories. This can be explained by the following picture.[image: Categorised Multiple File uploads within a page in Drupal 7]

As you can see I need to upload multiple files, but also need to categorize them. Each category has different files and even though below picture shows the same name of the files, they are not shared. How can I do it in Drupal 7. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a cross site duplicate: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/106070/categorised-multiple-file-uploads-within-a-page-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [File Entity](https://drupal.org/project/file_entity) module makes fieldable entities out of files. Which means you can use fields on files like you do on nodes, taxonomy terms and users. Use it to add a Taxononmy Reference field to the various file types (files types are like content types). Once done, you can build a your page using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views).